# Setting a default namespace for new projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

What template or setting can I modify to set up a default namespace for new projects?
I want all the namespaces to begin with the company name and I don't want to have to change it each time I create a new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go to the project properties to set the default namespace. This is normally on the `Application` tab, under... `Default Namespace`.

Now, if you want every *new* project to have this namespace - create a company project template where you have set it. Project templates are not difficult to create - see [this howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I was hoping that it would ber possible to set it at the solution level so that every new project under the solution would begin with the same namespace. I was also hoping that it would be somewhat easier then creating custom templates. I find it difficult to get a custom template to predictably get pushed into the template cache folders.